# R: Inserting a data frame into an array/Replace a dimension of an array

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe

a quite basic question. How do you replace a dimension of an array with a dataframe of the correct size (=matching the array in the other two dimensions)?

A simple working example: I make a small array of nrow=2, ncol=3, and 2 dimensions. I make a small dataframe which is also nrow=2 and ncol=3. If I try to replace one of the array's dimensions with the dataframe, it doesn't work properly and the array's dimensions are all messed up. What am I doing wrong?

```
arr<-array(1:12, dim=c(2,3,2))           

df<-data.frame(13:14,  15:16, 17:18)    

arr[,,2]<-df                            
dim(arr)
```

Comment: Try `arr[,,2] <- as.matrix(df) `. `array` coerces objects of non-atomic classes to vectors, hence the messed up output.

Comment: That works perfectly, I see! But what if the dataframe has vectors of different classes, though? I will need to do that next and could use a more generic solution :)

Comment: It will work too, `matrix` will convert them to the most basic atomic class (character). Try `df<-data.frame(13:14,  as.character(15:16), factor(17:18))  ; arr[,,2]<-as.matrix(df)`

Comment: Fantastic, I understand. You were fast and clear, thanks!